# Driver power state failure

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, dell-inspiron, bsod

Everytime I start my computer(runs on windows 8.1), the desktop appears and after a few seconds I get the blue screen and the message("driver power state failure"). Restarted my laptop on safe mode and checked the drivers. Found out that I have 3 problematic ones(yellow mark on each of the following):

```
---> Generic PnP monitor
--->Intel (R) Serial IO 12C Host Controller-9CE1
--->Intel (R) Serial IO 12C Host Controller-9CE2.
```

Does anyone know what should i do? Is this a problem that can be fixed by uninstalling and re-installing those drivers, or should I begin to worry?
Thank you!

Comment: we need to analyze the crash dump to help you. Copy he folder **c:\Windows\Minidump** to your desktop, zip the folder, upload the zip to Onedrive, create a share link and post the share link here.

Comment: have you uploaded the dmp files?

Comment: because you don't share the dump files I voted to close the question as "too broad"